# Best way to iterate 1 to 10 times and add value and to numpy array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I know this is a simple question for someone, but I'm lost here.

Say if I want my result to be 10 random numbers in an array value:

```
np.random.randint(0,2)  # returns 0,1
```

I want to iterate 10 times:

```
for i=1 to 10 : 
   np.random.randint(0,2) addto myarray
```

I want a numpy array of`0,1,1,0...` 10 times

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Reading the documentation is always a good idea.  If you type `help(np.random.randint)`, you see:

```
randint(...)
    randint(low, high=None, size=None)

    Return random integers from `low` (inclusive) to `high` (exclusive).

    Return random integers from the "discrete uniform" distribution in the
    "half-open" interval [`low`, `high`). If `high` is None (the default),
    then results are from [0, `low`).

    Parameters
    ----------
    low : int
        Lowest (signed) integer to be drawn from the distribution (unless
        ``high=None``, in which case this parameter is the *highest* such
        integer).
    high : int, optional
        If provided, one above the largest (signed) integer to be drawn
        from the distribution (see above for behavior if ``high=None``).
    size : int or tuple of ints, optional
        Output shape. Default is None, in which case a single int is
        returned.
```

and the very first example is:

```
Examples
--------
>>> np.random.randint(2, size=10)
array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
```

Comment: +1 for teaching a man to fish.